# Android Studio creating new activity has no "Blank activity" choice

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

Each time I tried to create new phone project with AS and adding new activity (as show in the illu) I can not see "Blank activity" in the menu of items.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is simply no Blank Activity. Android Studio change the Blank Activity into Basic Activity

Comment: Thank you, I was following an old tutorial :)

Answer (score 0):

Select java class and extend AppCompatActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 // set here your layout by using setContentView
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```